# How do I make a custom error page for people who try to connect to a page without internet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, offline

I want to have a custom error page for whenever you lose internet/try to enter the website without internet, yet I can't find any tutorials. I know it's possible because the Toontown Rewritten website has one as depicted by the image on my website, which can be found [here](https://www.theplayerzero.com/assets/img/errors/You%27re%20Offline.png)!

I've tried using an inspect element to figure it out but I cannot figure out what the javascript code is. I assume it's javascript since it's used in the code here:
```

You're Offline! | Toontown Rewritten


body {
background: #f3f3f3 url('/assets/images/base/gags_pattern.png');
background-position: 0 80px;
}

````
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.toontownrewritten.com/fonts/fonts.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/styles/style.css">

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/assets/images/icons/favicon-16x16.png?v=2">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Toontown">
<meta name="application-name" content="Toontown">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#1a5493">
</head>

<body data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.975.0" data-gr-ext-installed="">

<div class="content">
<div class="error__container">

<div class="error__info">
<div class="block">
<h1><b>Ouch.</b></h1>
<p>Looks like you've lost connection to the internet! If you ask us, that Cog probably had something to do with it.</p>
<p>Try checking your connection for loose Cog gears and then load this page again.</p>
<br>
<p><a class="link--featured" onclick="location.reload(true)"><b>Reload Page</b> 
</a></p>
<p><a class="link--featured" href="/"><b>Return to Home</b></a></p>
</div>
</div>
enter code here
            <div class="error__cog">
                <img src="/assets/images/pages/toons/cog_1ton.png">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Register service worker
        if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js');
        }
</script>




</body>
</html>```
````

And I'm sure other sites use it, but this is the only site that I know of that uses that.

I'm sure it's obvious, but seeing that I'm new to programming, I figured that I'd ask for help on the site that seems to have it all!

Thanks!

Comment: how do you intent to make it possible? a website is downloaded into a cache and displayed when you connect to it. If you have no internet, you cant dosnlaod the inofrmation for that website and tehrefor also not show a custom error page. So simply put, it is not possible. With no internet you also have no way to download a custom error page.

Comment: If you go to https://www.toontownrewritten.com/ and without internet, you'll see that it's possible.

Comment: cant confirm that, I got the standard no connection error page. I guess you just have the website cached.

Comment: Why would I do that and then make this question? There's literally no point.

Comment: I can't think of any way to do that, the comment from tacoshy is spot-on: if people can't reach your site, how would you execute anything? One thing that could be done though is a strategy for when people are already on your site and lose connection. If you have a SPA, appart from the initial load, you can handle further failing calls somewhat gracefully or even rely on local storage to display things or even collect info from the user, which should then be sent later to the server when connection is back up.

Comment: @tacoshy well said, at least one time you must need internet. You can check https://link.medium.com/xu2cVcvV6xb blog

Answer (score 1):

To detect when the user is offline you have different choices:

1 - [Online/Offline events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events) - Simple to achieve and does not involve a service worker, but as stated in the docs themselves not reliable

> Unfortunately, these events aren't fully reliable. If you need greater reliability, or if the API isn't implemented in the browser, you can use other signals to detect if you are offline including using service workers and responses from XMLHttpRequest.

```
function updateOnlineStatus(event) {
    const status = navigator.onLine ? "online" : "offline";

    // TODO: if OFFLINE -> Navigate to your 404 page
    // Put here your redirection code
  }

  window.addEventListener('online',  updateOnlineStatus);
  window.addEventListener('offline', updateOnlineStatus);
```

2 - [Service Worker](https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f) - This is without doubts the most elegant and reliable solution even if it requires to implement a service worker to detect the user connectivity status.

[Here](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/custom-offline-page/) you can find a code example about implementing a Service Worker to redirect to a custom offline page (404.html)

Comment: Is this implemented correctly: https://www.theplayerzero.com/assets/js/line.js, and of course, I have a statement in all of the pages that calls line.js from its directory.

Comment: The if statement must be inside the updateOnlineStatus function. Moreover inside the if, you must use `updateOnlineStatus === 'offline' to check the value, otherwise with just one = you attempt to initialise a variable.

Comment: Is this correct? https://www.theplayerzer.com/assets/js/line.js

Comment: You have to move the if block inside the `updateOnlineStatus`, so that you can verify the changing of status variable and execute the redirect accordingly. The best way would be to create an example (with stackblitz for example)

Answer (score 0):

make a 404.html file
search up netlify, firebase and watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPtS4vO42II

Comment: I already have an error 404 page, but I want one that comes up whenever you lose internet connection/don't have internet while trying to connect to the webpage.

Comment: well yeah to have one you need to use a service like netlify or firebase

Comment: Does that list include NameCheap @lambsbaaacode?

Comment: is that what you're using to host your domain?